# Failed to initialise build environment

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto

I am trying to build "yocto" with "jethro" (https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases) version but when I try initialise build environment it gives following error.

```
Error: 'meta-poky/conf' must be a directory containing local.conf & 
bblayers.conf
```

I found out that meta-poky folder is not available in jethro version.
What am I doing wrong in initialisation?

I tried with later version krogoth and it is working fine with it.

Comment: To the folks voting to close: this is not question about "generic hardware or software": Yocto is a toolset for building embedded operating systems

Comment: @jku: Which mean software/OS installation. Which is not a programming problem. Read [ask].

Comment: @olaf questions about software development tools are on topic. I would definitely argue Yocto falls in to that category: some yocto users may be "only" distro engineers but most are embedded software developers.

Comment: @jku "questions about software development tools are on topic." - Not always. Installing and configuring an Ubuntu distro is basically the same as what's asked here and definitively OT, even if it is used for software development.

Comment: @olaf installing Ubuntu and building an operating system using Yocto are _really_ not the same, not even approximately. Also Ubuntu is not "a tool primarily used for software development" as defined in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. That said, I don't object to people voting the way the feel: I just wanted everyone to have the required information before they do.

Comment: @jku: Ubuntu (or one of its flavours) is most likely used more often to develop software then yocto actually. Whether it compiles the actual distribution is quite irrelevant. Btw: it would be much the same for Gentoo instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

meta-yocto was indeed renamed meta-poky in Krogoth. There is code to handle your configuration in the upgrade case (going from jethro to krogoth) but downgrade probably isn't tested: I'm guessing you did a build with a newer release and then jethro.

This could *maybe* be fixed by just modifying `conf/templateconf.cfg` & `conf/bblayers.conf` manually (to refer to "meta-yocto" instead of "meta-poky"). Alternatively you could move your whole conf/ out of the way, re-generate a template configuration with `. oe-init-build-env` and then redo any local configuration you had.